# querySelector in Apache Batik

Tags: css, dom, batik

I'd like to query an Apache Batik DOM for elements which match a CSS selector.

Does Batik provide an alternative to any of the following browser DOM methods?

- [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)
- [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)
- [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector)
- [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's the solution I've managed to put together. It's written in Clojure instead of Java, but the important bits are:

1. Instantiate org.apache.batik.css.engine.sac.CSSConditionFactory
2. Instantiate org.apache.batik.css.parser.Parser
3. Call Parser.parseSelectors
4. Call org.apache.batik.dom.traversal.TraversalSupport.createNodeIterator
5. In your NodeFilter, iterate over the parsed SelectorList, calling ExtendedSelector.match
6. Conditionally skip the first node returned from the iterator (it's always the traversal root)

```clojure
(def ^:private condition-factory
  (CSSConditionFactory. nil "class" nil "id"))

(defn- parse-selector [selector]
  (let [parser (Parser.)]
    (doto parser
      (.setSelectorFactory CSSSelectorFactory/INSTANCE)
      (.setConditionFactory condition-factory))
    (.parseSelectors parser selector)))

(defn- matches?
  ([selector element] (matches? selector element ""))
  ([selector element pseudo]
   (let [length (.getLength selector)]
     (loop [i 0]
       (if (< i length)
         (if (.. selector (item i) (match element pseudo))
           true
           (recur (inc i)))
         false)))))

(defn selection-seq [root selector]
  (let [selector (parse-selector selector)
        iterator (.createNodeIterator (TraversalSupport.)
                   (.getOwnerDocument root)
                   root
                   NodeFilter/SHOW_ELEMENT
                   (reify NodeFilter
                     (acceptNode [_ element]
                       (if (matches? selector element)
                         NodeFilter/FILTER_ACCEPT
                         NodeFilter/FILTER_REJECT)))
                   false)
        node-seq ((fn step []
                    (lazy-seq
                      (when-let [node (.nextNode iterator)]
                        (cons node (step))))))]
    ;; Iterator always returns the reference node, so match it.
    (when-let [node (first node-seq)]
      (if (matches? selector (first node-seq))
        node-seq
        (next node-seq)))))
```